# omar khayyam work on ODE (ordinary differential equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, math-history

I wanted to know if Omar Khayyam did work on ODE and if there is any connection between that and the cubic  equations.

Comment: Omar Khayam has worked on solution of polynomial of degree 3 ,4 and 5 but I am not sure that he also has worked on PDE or ODE

Answer (score 3):

While elements of Newton's *Principia* draws upon the classical method of exhaustion from the Greeks, as well as some contemporary work of other mathematicians (e.g. John Wallis' *Arithmetica Infinitorum*), there is no known record of *calculus* having been discovered/invented (depending on your point of view) independently prior to the, say, [13th century](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuktibh%C4%81%E1%B9%A3%C4%81).

Based on that, the *known facts* do not point toward Omar Khayyam having even the *language* in which to write down a differential equation, let along doing work in it.